# show only subdocument entries with that match criteria in a document - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Lets say this is the data (

```
{ _id: 1, results: [ { product: "abc", score: 10 }, { product: "ecf", score: 5 } ] } 
{ _id: 2, results: [ { product: "abc", score: 8 }, { product: "xya", score: 7 } ] } 
{ _id: 3, results: [ { product: "abc", score: 7 }, { product: "xyz", score: 8 }, { product: "xyz", score: 8 } ] }
```

I understand that I can make queries like `db.inventory.find( { "results.product": "xyz"} )` and get the documents that matches the query. 
But what I really want is get the subdocuments that fit the criteria.

Example, MY query should return just the below result instead of all the subdocuments in the document. We can assume that i want to do this operation on a single document( i mean, applying `_id: 3` explicitly in the query.

`{ _id: 3, results: [  { product: "xyz", score: 8 } ] }`

**UPDATE:**
I found some answer from some stackoverflow post and based on that, i modified the query accordingly, something like this -   `db.collection.find({'results.product': "xyz"}, {'results.$' : 1})` this is actually returning only 1 subdocument in `results` field which matches the criteria

Am i missing something!

**UPDATED 2:**

```
{
  _id: 1,
  title: "123 Department Report",
  tags: [ "G", "STLW" ],
  year: 2014,
  subsections: [
    {
      subtitle: "Section 1: Overview",
      content:  "Section 1: This is the content of section 1."
    },
    {
      subtitle: "Section 2.a: Analysis",
      content: "Section 2: This is the content of section 2."
    },
    {
      subtitle: "Section 2.b: Advanced Analysis",
      content: "Section 2: This is the content of section 2."
    },
    {
      subtitle: "Section 3: Budgeting",
      content: "Section 3: This is the content of section3."
    }
  ]
}
```

the above is a modified version of the example from https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#examples

the query should return the following data, assuming im looking for `analysis` word in `subsections.subtitle` field.

```
{
  _id: 1,
  title: "123 Department Report",
  tags: [ "G", "STLW" ],
  year: 2014,
  subsections: [
    {
      subtitle: "Section 2.a: Analysis",
      content: "Section 2: This is the content of section 2."
    },
    {
      subtitle: "Section 2.b: Advanced Analysis",
      content: "Section 2: This is the content of section 2."
    } 
  ]
}
```

Comment: You probably looking for the reverse condition, but have a look here(removed just the matching document): https://github.com/rahul-raj/MongoDB/blob/master/mongo-query-1.txt 
let me know once u find a solution accordingly.

Comment: It isnt the solution to ur question, u might want to add some tweak to above query.

Comment: hey, i see that you are using $ne , which is a full text match !! but im looking for substring match actually.. sorry the example doesn't speak about substring, but that's what i was looking for

Comment: Because u have added direct match condition in ur question. Use ´$regex´ for substring match.

Comment: @RahulRaj, updated the question, can you look in to it!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167460/discussion-between-rrmerugu-and-rahul-raj).

Comment: The subject line may look same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection , but an exact match is used in the mentioned post rather than matching for a pattern. `$regex` cant be used with `cond` operator or in `$filter`.

Comment: closest result that I could reach so far: https://github.com/rahul-raj/MongoDB/blob/master/mongo-query-1.txt

Comment: @RahulRaj, that works for this scenario much better.

Comment: @RahulRaj, if you can post the answer here, i will mark it as final answer.

Comment: cant post as an answer, since this post has been flagged by someone.